# How this finite subgroup can contain an element has an infinite order???

Tags: group-theory

I am solving the following exercice:

> le $G$ be a group, $m\in \mathbb{N}^{*}\cup \{{\infty}\}$ and $G_{m}=\langle x\in G | |x|=m\rangle$.
>
> Assume that $G_{m}$ finite $\forall m \in \mathbb {N}^{*}\cup \{\infty\}$.
>
> Prove that $G$ is an FC periodic group.

My problem is that I couldn't understand how a finite subgroup can contain an element has an infinite order? would sombody explain to me, according to the exercice (If $x$ has an infinite order then  $m=\infty \in G_{m}$ which is finite ).

Comment: A finite subgroup cannot contain an element of infinite order.

Comment: but in that example by definition of the subgroup it can contain an infinite element

Comment: That $G_\infty$ be finite is equivalent for it to have no elements.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez can we say that $G_{\infty} = 1$

Comment: @Meriem dumb question : what does the FC stand for?

Comment: @rschwieb means that every element has  finite conjugates

Comment: @Meriem ahh, thanks

Answer (score 3):

There exists an element of infinite order iff $G_\infty$ has an element of infinite order, whence it is infinite. By hypothesis it is finite, so the group is periodic.

The conjugates of an element share the same order, so they all lie in the same $G_m$. By hypothesis again, these are all finite, so the group is FC.